# Validate Custom Login field

Tags: login, authentication

I have added an extra login field to the main wordpress login page. It is a checkbox which must be checked (to accept terms & conditions), otherwise the user cannot log in.

[I have taken code from this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45900/adding-extra-authentication-field-in-login-page) 
which has allowed me to add a custom checkbox to the login. However, trying to modify the code given to validate whether the checkbox has been checked, I cannot get to work.

```
function check_checkbox($user) {
    $acceptance = $_POST['terms_acceptance'];

    $user = get_user_by('login', $username );

    if( !$user || !isset($acceptance) ){
        remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);

        $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: You're unique identifier was invalid.") );
    }

    return null;
}
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'check_checkbox', 10, 3 );
```

I have tried the 'authenticate' & 'wp_authenticate_user' filters as shown, but neither have worked for me.

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the full working code, put it in **functions.php**:

```
add_action('login_form','my_added_login_field');
function my_added_login_field(){
?>
    <p>
        <label for="my_extra_field">I agree to the terms<br />
        <input type="checkbox" value="1" class="input" id="my_extra_field" name="my_extra_field_name"/></label>
    </p>
<?php
}

function check_checkbox($user, $password)
{
    if( !isset($_POST['my_extra_field_name']) )
     {
        remove_action('authenticate', 'wp_authenticate_username_password', 20);
        $user = new WP_Error( 'denied', __("<strong>ERROR</strong>: Please agree to our terms.") );
    }

    return $user;
}
add_filter( 'wp_authenticate_user', 'check_checkbox', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: works well with, WP 4.6.+

Answer (score 0):

[Per the Codex...](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_authenticate_user)

```
add_filter('wp_authenticate_user', 'myplugin_auth_login',10,2);
function myplugin_auth_login ($user, $password) {
     //do any extra validation stuff here
     return $user;
}
```

You need to return the `$user` object. Your function *always* returns `null`. This is completely untested but it looks like you just need to use `return $user;` on the last line instead of `return null;`